iptables UDP packet forwarding keeping the original destination IP address
All Output UDP packets: Destination_IP:44124
are redirected to a local UDP Server: 192.168.1.5:44123 using the following iptables rule:
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 44124 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.5:44123
Does anyone know a way to retain the destination IP of the output UDP packet when arriving to the UDP server?  The above rule shows destination IP: 192.168.1.5.
Example: If run: echo "This is the message." > /dev/udp/192.168.1.10/44124
I would like that the UDP server sees destination IP = 192.168.1.10 instead of 192.168.1.5
